# how can I fully disable resizing a window including the resize icon when the mouse hovers the border?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, border

I used: 
`setFixedSize(size());`
to stop the window from resizing, but the resize arrows still appear when the mouse is over the border of the window.

Is there a better way to disable window resizing to avoid showing the arrows when crossing the border?

Comment: What OS are you using? Have you tried using dialog instead of window?

Comment: Windows 8. developing for desktop. I'm just created new project. do u think dialog will be isue?

Comment: Well, in my WinXp the only place, where arrows appeared (after setting fixed size) is bottom right corner (the one with a triangle). In dialog (after setting fixed size) - no arrows appeared.

Comment: I will try use dialog.

Comment: You may try setting size policy to QSizePolicy::Fixed

Comment: ariwez '<property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>' its seted up. but it wont listen. its resizing anyway....

Comment: Amartel: dialog is same.

Comment: Could you, please, comment on the answer, how you got this working? Having the same problem right now, but the object parameter is never QSizeGrip, therefore, I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: setFixedSize(size()) works for me. Perhaps it was an old Qt bug or something else is overriding your call after you make it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Qt has a windowFlag called `Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint` for that. Depending on what you exactly want, you want to combine this flag with `Qt::Widget`, `Qt::Window` or `Qt::Dialog`.

```
void MyDialog::MyDialog()
{
  setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);

  ...
}
```

Comment: @dsonck92: i tried this one and it works fine but for what I want to achieve I still have one leakage. Goal: MAXIMIZED + NON-RESIZABLE WINDOW. Result: Window shows maximized and with border grip and maximize button disabled, good so far. Leakage: I can still "pull" it away from the top of the screen and when I do so, it goes back to its default size (default as in QtCreator's fresh new app window size) which btw I can't maximize again, obviously, not even "throwing" it back to the top of the screen, please any insights.. thanx. using qtcreator 3.0.0 based on qt 5.2.0

Comment: this is the only one that I found that works for Windows 7 and 10

Comment: This worked for me in Python, thanks!

self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Dialog | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)

Comment: What about disabling only vertical and both-dimensions grips but leaving horizontal one enabled?

Comment: Doesn't work if the dock widget detached.

Answer (score 26):

One-liner if you know exactly the required size of the window:

```
this->setFixedSize(QSize(750, 400));
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Doesn't work if the dock widget detached.

Comment: This doesn't work for windows that are auto-layed out using layouts. Even after configuring all the layouts and adding widgets to them, calling `setFixedSize` even with the window's height and width doesn't work correctly. I want the window to auto-layout itself but disable resizing.

Answer (score 20):

Try something like this:

```
this->statusBar()->setSizeGripEnabled(false);
```

If this doesn't work, all you need to do is detect what widget is activating [QSizeGrip](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsizegrip.html). You can do this by installing an event filter on your app and try to catch the QSizeGrip's mouseMoveEvent. Then debug its parent widget.

Here's an example of the eventFilter function you could use:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        QSizeGrip *sg = qobject_cast<QSizeGrip*>(obj);
        if(sg)
            qDebug() << sg->parentWidget();
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could probably catch its show event as well, it's up to you.

Comment: Using windows 10, I had to use both this answer and the next (windowFlag `Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint`)

Answer (score 12):

If using Qt Designer, set your window's "sizePolicy" properties to "Fixed" in the vertical and horizontal directions and set minimum and maximum dimensions to equal values.  Then, right-click on the window and select "Remove Status Bar" to get rid of the "size grip" in the bottom-right corner.  Or, remove just the size grip via the suggestion from francis (rather than the entire status bar).

Comment: Worth noting you'll then need to set the minimum/maximum dimensions to be equal and to the size of the window in your editor. This will disable resizing.

Answer (score 12):

I found that calling setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize) on the layout worked the best for me.  Specifically, from a QMainWindow constructor, I called:

```
this->layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
```

Here's a link to the docs:  http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#SizeConstraint-enum

(I'm using Qt 4.8.)

Since this was also a simple way to solve the OP's question, I thought I would share it for others to consider.  It appears that there are many ways to accomplish this in Qt, but not all may be ideal for every situation.  I tried several of the other options posted here, but they had various issues or constraints that I wasn't happy with in my own situation.

Comment: best solution if you are programatically adding widgets and don't know the size after the construct.

Comment: Just a note about a dock widget (Qt 5.9.7 tested). If you set this constraint on the window (`QMainWindow` in my case) containing a dock widget the behavior is as follows : if you detach the dock via double click on it, everything is fine, But if you drag the dock widget with your mouse the main window doesn't resize BUT the widgets inside do. So the "solution" I've found is to add the following features to my dock widgets : `setFeatures( QDockWidget::DockWidgetClosable | QDockWidgetFloatable )`. So you can't drag the dock with mouse but still can detach it. Don't know if it generates issues.

Answer (score 5):

Use

**setMinimumSize**(QSize(width_px,height_px))

**setMaximumSize**(QSize(width_px,height_px))

where both methods have ***same*** size.You won't see the resize cursor & the window thus doesn't get resized/maximized.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to obtain the values of width and height from the UI form itself without manually specifying, then you can add the following command inside your project class:

```
this->setFixedSize(this->width(), this->height());
```

You can also set separate parameters for width and height (if required) with:

```
this->setFixedWidth(this->width());
this->setFixedHeight(this->height());
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [Qt Creator](http://www.qt.io/ide), you can *try* to specify the same `Width` and `Height` of the window in the `properties` of `geometry`, `minimumSize` and `maximumSize`.

Answer (score 3):

This helped me with Qt Creator 3.1.1:

```
this->setFixedSize(this->maximumSize());
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all in Qt 5.9.7

Answer (score 3):

You can in Qt5 use following code

```
this->setMinimumSize(sz);
this->setMaximumSize(sz);
```

Where sz is QSize object.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can just do something like:

```
this->setFixedWidth(int);
this->setFixedHeight(int);
```

The arrows are gone too.

Answer (score 2):

If someone looking for the same, but in Python:

```
    MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
```

Comment: This will overwrite *all* other flags in order to set this flag.  If you wish to set this flag alone, `setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint, True)` may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent resizing the window add this line:

`setFixedSize(width(), height());`

in your QMainWindow constructor after the line: `ui->setupUi(this);`.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that really worked for me on Windows 10 is using the WinAPI:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    #include <windows.h>

    ...

    SetWindowLong((HWND) window->winId(), GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong((HWND) window->winId(), GWL_STYLE)&~WS_SIZEBOX);

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The size is not known until the appearance and can vary by system settings too (100%, 125%, 150%), so you may try something like this (it also hides the resize-cursor):

```
void QWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    // disable vertical resize
    int height = this->height();
    if (height != minimumHeight() || height != maximumHeight()) {
        setMinimumHeight(height);
        setMaximumHeight(height);
    }
}
```