# setFixedSize doesn't work as expected

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5

I'm using the latest stable version of Qt 5 built statically with GCC 4.8 on Windows 8.

I've created a simple QMainWindow-based application with just one button. When I do `setFixedSize(minimumSizeHint())` the window gets resized as I want it to and the maximize button gets disabled, but I can still see the double-sided arrows, when I hover my pointer over the edges, and I can resize the window vertically by 14 pixels. If add another button or a status bar - nothing changes. If I add 14 pixels (or more) to the minimum height - it becomes truly fixed, but I can still see the arrows, which isn't normal.

This is very weird, because absolutely the same code (and its variations) works perfectly well in PyQt4 (please, note, I use C++ now). I tried:

- `layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize)` - same behavior
- `setWindowFlags(Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)` - the window just disappears

Any way to fix this?

**UPD**: I was wrong about adding another button (apparently, it isn't the same as adding a status bar) - it isn't possible to resize the window anymore (though, why would Qt let me set the height of the window less than it likes...), but the arrows are still there.

**UPD 2**: Found a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673074/fully-disable-window-resize), but the answer didn't help (for the reasons described in a comment to the question itself).

Comment: Wow, it didn't occur to me, that the order in which I call `setWindowFlags` and `show` could matter :) If I put it before `show` - works like a charm. If you post this as an answer - I'll accept it. [The bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31519) I submitted a bit earlier.

Comment: I changed my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sizegrip thing seems to work differently in Qt 5. Don't know if it's a bug or not. I tried setting the `Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint` flag for my main window and it seems to work fine for me. I'm on windows 7 though.

As it says in the documentation about the [setWindowFlags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) function:
`Note: This function calls setParent() when changing the flags for a window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call show() to make the widget visible again..`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to behave identically to what you had in PyQt4, you could just program in C++ using the same version of Qt that the PyQt project is using:  Qt 4.8.4

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedSize

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, building Qt again is the very last option (and I can't just download it, because I need it to be static). And they are supposed to be the same anyway, check out the docs side-by-side: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#setFixedSize