# Qt Linux/XP difference - making window unresizable by user

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

in my class that inherits QMainWindow, I have a resize method that resizes the window and then makes it unresizable to user input:

```
this->setMaximumSize(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX, QWIDGETSIZE_MAX);
this->resize(this->width(), this->height() + newSize);
this->setFixedSize(this->size());
```

It works perfectly on `Linux`, but on `Windows` it leaves the window resizable to user input. I'm not sure how that's possible, since it's identical code and the last call IS `setFixedSize`, which should disable resizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several questions about related problems on Stackoverflow already:

- [Non-resizeable QDialog with fixed size in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696209/non-resizeable-qdialog-with-fixed-size-in-qt)
- [setFixedSize doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885974/setfixedsize-doesnt-work-as-expected)
- [In Qt C++, how can I fully disable resizing a window including the resize icon when the mouse hovers the border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673074/how-can-i-fully-disable-resizing-a-window-including-the-resize-icon-when-the-mou?lq=1)

The solution might be to use the `Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint` QWindowFlag, or to set the parent layout (the main widget layout) to non-resizable, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151867/256138):

```
window->layout()->setSizeConstraint( QLayout::SetFixedSize );
```

Comment: Apparently using `setSizeConstraint` has no effect either

Comment: yeah, I tried everything on those questions, no effect whatsoever. I can still drag the window size vertically on Windows, but not on Linux.