# Qt QMainWindow disable manual resize, but not automatic one

Tags: c++, qt

is it possible to disable manual user-drag resize of a window, but keep it resizeable programatically for when a widget inside it expands and has to expand the window with itself?

Comment: Have you tried disabling resize by user, and then tried resizing programmatically? Why do you think it won't work?

Comment: It works automatically right now as long as it's not set ot a fixed size. If I set it to fixed size, then expanding widgets inside the window doesn't expand the window.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673074/how-can-i-fully-disable-resizing-a-window-including-the-resize-icon-when-the-mou