# How to removed resize cursor?

Tags: c++, qt

If I point sideways at the windows the cursor shows the resize option.
I want to disable this option.

Fixed size mainWindow.
`w.setMinimumSize(QSize(960,680)); w.setMaximumSize(QSize(960,680)); w.setFixedSize(w.maximumSize());`
[show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us8c4.png)

Comment: You'll find a couple options for doing this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673074/how-can-i-fully-disable-resizing-a-window-including-the-resize-icon-when-the-mou